# T-SQL- What does N' means in rowpattern (xpath)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath, openxml

I cannot understand the xml rowpattern of the following code in T-SQL.

```
OPENXML(@hDoc, N'//item')
```

All the examples that I found in msdn were like `/ROOT/Customer`, but I don't understand  `N'//item'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `N` before any string in SQL Server marks the string as Unicode.

Essentially, the difference between `char/varchar/text` and `nchar/nvarchar/ntext`.